# Adding colored ribbon and image to title page

Tags: color, titles, boxes, logos

I'd like to add a colored ribbon (a rectangular box) and a logo image to the top of my title page.

The title of the document is on the center of the page, and I would like for it to stay there.

As for the ribbon and image, the ribbon should span from the left edge of the page (not margin) to about 3/4 of its width. The logo should be placed to the right of the ribbon, in the remaining quarter (or so) of the page's width. Both elements should be a few centimeters away from the top of the page.

Any idea how I could​ accomplish that?

I'm currently on mobile, but can make s mock-up in Scribus when I get home. I know that I can design the page in Scrib and just include it, but I'd like to know how to do it in Latex.

Comment: Please to mock something up. Pictures are worth a thousand words...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `titling` package, you can have a title page along these lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{garamondx}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{About John Ford}
\author{The author}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\centering\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\color{yellow}\rule{\dimexpr0.75\paperwidth}{2cm}}%
\makebox[\dimexpr 0.25\paperwidth]{\quad\adjincludegraphics[height =5cm, valign=c]{SheWore}}}}
 \setlength\droptitle {-5cm}
\pretitle{\vspace{3cm}\begin{center}\Huge\itshape\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}\vskip2cm}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\postauthor{\end{center}\vfill}%
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :) I'd like to get a little better understanding of the code you're using - do you have some useful reference, besides the texdocs? Like a site where I can  get tips about various commands and so on?

Comment: There's of course the documentation of `titling` which has the explanations for  `\maketitlehooka-d and `\droptitle`For the rest there's not much really. `\centering\makebox[0pt]{contents}`  is a standard way to centre a contents which may be wider than `\textwidth` *between the margins*. The numerical values I use were found by trial and error. Finally, `adjustbox` is an extension of `graphicx` with more built-in possibilities. Feel free to ask for any explanation about a part of the code, but the best is perhaps to play first  with the parameters to see what happens when they're changed.

Comment: Okay, thanks! :) Can this code also be used inside the text? Like for a part-of-the-report title page?

Comment: I don't think you can use the code which is specific to `titling`, but you certainly can use the code for the ribbon and image in a redefinition of `\part` with package `titlesec`, using  the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`commands. You should take a look at its documentation.